# CORS issue with PHP - Preflight request

Tags: php, angularjs, cors

I am having `CORS` issue with PHP. I have following code in my angular:

```
 $http({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer zPwDlSp5AKv7MnZRwWyULhavD3WmTFPH',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data: JSON.stringify({'user_id': '17'})
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log('Success!');
        console.log(response.data);
    }, function(response) {
        console.log('Failed!');
        console.log(response);
    })
```

And following php code in backend:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

However, headers are set correctly I got:-

> preflight request error.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load "url". Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 400

Comment: With exception of missing a couple of methods [this is a much better php cors implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966)

Comment: why are you using stringify when angular $http does that internally? And *"didn't work"* tells us next to nothing of value